# Remove rows in pandas dataframe where column doesnot matches a dataype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like:

```
A     B    C
abc   10   20
def   30   50  
cfg   90   60
70   str  50
xyz   75   56
```

I want to get rid of the 4th row where datatypes are not matching

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path+files, delimiter='\t', error_bad_lines=False)
df.dtypes
```

```
A       object
B        int64
C       object
dtype: object
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say this isn't a trivial problem to solve, if you don't know what dtypes your column are.

For the purpose of this problem I'll assume you only have strings and numeric types in your DataFrame.

```
v = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isna() 
df[~((x.mean() >=.5) ^ x)].dropna()

     A   B   C
0  abc  10  20
1  def  30  50
2  cfg  90  60
4  xyz  75  56
```

The idea here is to drop rows which do not share the dtype of the majority of your data.